# src/main/scala folder disappears on clicking 'update project' in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven

I am doing a simple Scala example using Eclipse and Maven. As an example, I am doing a simple JSON Parsing example.

Below are the steps I followed:

1. Click on File followed by New and Other to Create a new Maven Project.
2. Right-click on the project, click on configure and click 'Add Scala Nature'.
3. Right-click on src/main/java, click on refractor and rename Java to Scala.
   The folder structure now changes to

> src/main/scala

4. Right-click on the project, click on build and make sure it is pointing to the correct JRE.
5. Add the below dependency under dependencies:

> ```
> <dependency>
> <groupId>net.liftweb</groupId>
> <artifactId>lift-json_2.11</artifactId>
> <version>2.6.2</version>
>  </dependency>
> ```

6. Right-click on the project, click on New, select package and create a package with name com.test
7. Right-click on the project, click on New, Select new scala object and give the name JsonParser.

Add the below code:

```
package com.test

    import net.liftweb.json._
    import scala.reflect.ManifestFactory.classType

    object JsonParsing{

      implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
      case class Mailserver(url: String, username: String, password: String)

      val json = parse(
        """
    { 
      "url": "imap.yahoo.com",
      "username": "myusername",
      "password": "mypassword"
    }
    """)

      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val m = json.extract[Mailserver]
        println(m.url)
        println(m.username)
        println(m.password)
      }

    }
```

The project at this stage has build errors due to dependency. I follow step 8.

8. Right-click on the project, click on maven and click 'Update project'.

As soon as I do this, the folder src/main/scala disappears and now I can see only folders

> src/main/java, src/main/resources

and

> src/test/resources.

How do I get my below folder back:

> src/main/scala

Thank You.

Comment: Scala IDE is not mantained anymore, please switch to IntelliJ Idea or Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I also tried this in Eclipse IDE (with Scala plugin). The same problem occurs on clicking 'Update Project'.

Answer (score 1):

The default compiler plugin executes Java. When you run `Update Project` it runs the POM and makes the project in Eclipse look like the POM. I'd try using something like the [scala-maven-plugin](https://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/index.html). Then Maven will know this is a Scala project.

Comment: I added the dependency for scala-maven-plugin as below:   `<dependency>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency> `                                                                                                         On doing "update project" the result was the same. The mentioned folder disappeared.

Comment: It's not a dependency. It's a plugin. It needs to be added as such (in the `plugins` section).

Comment: I added the below plugin under plugins in POM.xml but the result was same : ` 
<plugin>
<groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>compile</goal>
<goal>testCompile</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
<sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
<jvmArgs>
<jvmArg>-Xms64m</jvmArg>
<jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
</jvmArgs>
</configuration>
</plugin>`

Comment: I will leave it to you to read and understand the documentation. I've never used this plugin, but I have configured Maven to work with other languages before, and typically additional plugins are required. This one seemed like a good candidate. Plus, you told it that the source directory was `src/main/java`.

Comment: Thank You, your answer was useful.The issue is resolved by creating a POM.xml similar to the one suggested in this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929100/running-a-scala-application-in-maven-project). This time on doing maven install, eclipse did not give any errors and 'update project' was not required. It worked fine.

Comment: You're welcome, I hoped this would lead you down a good path. I suggested answering your own question for the next person.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. I am not sure why on adding just the plugin as you said did not work but pasting the entire POM.xml as suggested in this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929100/running-a-scala-application-in-maven-project) resolved the issue.